# Compute lengths of the longest edge of each cell

Tags: python, fenics

Having

```
mesh = UnitSquareMesh(2, 2)
Q = FunctionSpace(mesh, 'DG', 0)
```

this works as expected

```
R = mesh.ufl_cell().circumradius
R = project(R, Q)
```

but this fails

```
h = mesh.ufl_cell().max_facet_edge_length
h = project(h, Q)
```

when compiling generated code with error: 'facet_area' was not declared...

Does max_facet_edge_length return **lengths of the longest edge of a cell** as I expected or does it do something else? If so, is there some implementation of this? Or should I loop over cells and their edges to compute h manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, **lengths of the longest edge of a cell** `h` can be computed pythonically - i.e. not efficiently

```
h = Function(Q)
for c in cells(mesh):
    h.vector()[c.index()] = max(e.length() for e in edges(c))
```

---

For the clarification

```
mesh.ufl_cell().max_facet_edge_length
```

defines facet diameter (length of the longest edge) which can be evaluated on facets.
For example interior penalty stabilization can be implemented this way

```
h_F = mesh.ufl_cell().max_facet_edge_length
n = FacetNormal(mesh)
alpha = Constant(0.01)
F += alpha('+')*h_F**2*inner(jump(grad(u), n), jump(grad(v), n))*dS
```

`u` being stabilize quantity, `v` its test function and `alpha` stabilization parameter here taken as constant. But may be for example scaled with convecting velocity for convection-dominated problems. See http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-07-01951-5 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00211-007-0070-5